# Javascript weird syntax in function parameter

Tags: javascript

I am learning vue and I came across this weird syntax in defining a function, I am curious what it is called and where i can learn more about it

```
register({commit}, credentials){
}
```

Why are there brackets around `commit`? Shouldn't it just be simple:

```
register(commit, credentials){
}
```

What's the purpose of placing brackets around `commit` variable?

Answer (score 1):

This is object destructuring assignment. You can read about it on MDN here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Basically, your function's first parameter is an object that has a `commit` property. Destructuring lets you pull that property out of the object. Here's an example of destructuring being used (but not within function arguments):

```
const obj = {
  commit: "Hi there"
}

const { commit } = obj;
console.log(commit);
// "Hi there"
```